# Copy files to local computer while connect ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

So I am trying to find a way to copy a file while connected to a remote computer

```
cd /Desktop/dir
ssh remote_pc@remote_ip
password
cd my/dir
scp file.pdf __________
```

I know it works if I use "home_pc@home_ip.local:~/Desktop/dir" I am wondering if there is a way to skip "home_pc@home_ip.local:~/Desktop/dir" and just copy/paste to the directory I am in before I had  ssh

I know I can also copy the files with

```
  scp remote_pc@remote_ip:~/my/dir/file.pdf   ~/Desktop/dir
```

however this is difficult because I don't know all the file names and directories without looking for them and still having navigating to my directory with this method

Comment: Flagged - not a question about programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to ssh to the remote_ip? You could use this:

```
cd ~/Desktop/dir
scp remote_pc@remote_ip:/my/dir/file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do so using the same *active* SSH connection unless you use different ssh client for example `zssh` as illustrated at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13382/download-a-file-over-an-active-ssh-session). This assumes you have a) you can install it b) you can run it.

In effect, I would try a difference client.